# Neo4j merge query on a node with indexed constraint takes 4-6sec

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am running a Neo4j merge cypher query in my Java Application which performs a merge on a node with a label as well as a property which is indexed. Irrespective of match or create I am setting some properties on the matched or created node.
The query on an average takes close to 4-6sec.
Code snippet of the query:

```
@Query("MERGE (u:User {userId: {userId}}) set u.lat={lat}, u.lng={lng}, u.accuracy={accuracy}, "
      + " u.brandId={brandId}, u.updatedAt={updatedAt}, u.createdAt={createdAt} "
      + " return u")
  User saveUserCypher(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("lat") Double lat, @Param("lng") Double lng,
      @Param("accuracy") Integer accuracy, @Param("brandId") Integer brandId,
      @Param("updatedAt") String updatedAt, @Param("createdAt") String createdAt);
```

1. Neo4j server version: 3.3.2 (Community Edition)
2. StandAlone Machine
3. Server Hardware Conf: 72vCPU 144GB RAM (basically using c5d.18xlarge
   AWS EC2 instance to host the neo4j server)

I have already tried using Spring Data Neo4j save function and it takes even more time so I resorted back to writing cypher.
I have also increased the page cache size of the server to 60g.
Is such high query time expected? I was hoping for the query to be executed in subsecond. Please suggest what optimizations/improvement can be done?

Thanks in advance.
**Edit 1**: [Added the profile of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEdh2.png)

Comment: 1. Is there a reason for using a *very* old version of neo4j? 2. What exactly is the "constraint" that you already have? 3. How many `User` nodes exist? 4. Do you only want to set the properties if the node did not already exist, or do you really want to set them even if the node already existed?

Comment: Hello, @cybersam 1. There is no specific reason as to using this version. It's being used in prod from the beginning and we never performed a version upgrade. 2.Unique constraint on userId 3.More than 10Million nodes. 4. I want to set these properties even if the node already existed.

Comment: Can you show a [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of the query? Also, you may want to consider creating a new neo4j installation using the latest version (say, with some sample data, on your local machine), and seeing if the PROFILE is different.

Comment: @cybersam have edited the question to add the profile of the query. Somehow in the uploaded image arrows are not coming although its there when exporting the plan from Neo4j Browser. Can share the profile image via some other way if required. Regarding the installation of the latest version, will give it a try and get back.

Comment: (Seems like you are using a black background for the image --you probably should use a white bg.) Your profile shows only 7 DB hits, which I would expect to be 2 orders of magnitude faster than what you are reporting. Maybe the latest neo4j version will have faster results. But how much time did it take for the profile (which presumably was run in the neo4j browser?) take -- if it is much faster, than something about your Java app is slowing things down.

Comment: @cybersam Tried to change the bg color to white and upload but no luck regarding the arrows. Anyways regarding the run time of the profile which I shared, it ran in ~ 1-2ms but few points to be noted is that I ran it in stage env which has exact same hardware but does not receive any live traffic and is not updated real-time. At the time of setup, a one time clone of prod DB was done so it basically has around 5-6M User Nodes. Will an EXPLAIN of the query in prod DB give a better idea? Please advise. Parallelly I am also trying to run the query in the latest version.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` does not use live data, so it would not be helpful.